# Hull's book - Futures option's rho

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, greeks, european-options, black-scholes-merton

In Hull's book ([9th edition](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/1214184/mod_folder/content/0/Hull%20J.C.-Options%2C%20Futures%20and%20Other%20Derivatives_9th%20edition.pdf?forcedownload=1)), on page 420, in table 19.6, it says rho of a European call on an asset with yield $q$ is
$$KTe^{-rT}N(d_2)$$
Below it says we can compute greeks of European options on futures by setting $q=r$. But then it says the rho for a call futures option is $-cT$. I am a bit confused here. The price of a futures call option is
$$c=e^{-rT}(F_0N(d_1)-KN(d_2))$$
where the futures price $F_0=e^{rT}S_0$ when there is no dividend and interest rate is constant.
Then wouldn't the rho of this option be
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial r}=KTe^{-rT}N(d_2)$$
rather than
$$-cT=KTe^{-rT}N(d_2)-TS_0e^{-rT}N(d_1)?$$
Are we not treating $F_0$ as a function of $r$? What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you should treat the futures price as an exogeneous. The futures price is arrived at from supply and demand. Depending on your application, you *could* model the futures price as well, of course; for example when modelling bond futures options and such.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your option has exposure to interest rates for two different reasons:

- The discounting of (expected) terminal payoff.
- The forward (~cost of financing of the delta hedging).

Mathematically, if you note your call as a function of rates and of the forward (itself a function of rates) $C(r, F(r))$, you have by chain rule:

$$\frac{dC}{dr} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial F}\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}$$

The first RHS term $\frac{\partial C}{\partial r}$ comes from discounting the expected terminal payoff (i.e. the call present value).
The second RHS term comes from financing the call's replicating strategy. To replicate the call, you must hold a certain quantity of forward (which is the delta of the call $\frac{\partial C}{\partial F}$. And that forward has a sensitivity to interest rates $\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}$ which is the cost of funding the underlying asset.